# WCF Data Service REST Client - duplicated entries

Tags: wcf, odata

We are using the newest WCF dlls (5.6.1) to implement OData Client. We send a request to a service and we are supposed to get multiple, various entries. Unfortunately, something goes wrong and in the response we are getting the correct count of entries, which are incorrectly duplicated (The entry which is the last one is repeated by the count of entries). When the url, which is sent to the service, is executed in browser the entries in response are correct - every entry is different. The same situation is when in linq query I select only some of the columns by new{x.column1, x.column2} - every entry is different.

This is part of the response from browser:

```
<entry>
<id>...</id>
<title type="text">...</title>
<updated>2014-05-22T08:44:46Z</updated>
<category term="GET_AVG_CONS.Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<link href="Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR_COLLECTION(Customer='1000000167',CompCode='DE0J')" rel="edit" title="Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:BpCat/>
<d:Cusvalsg/>
<d:Salesorg/>
<d:Flag/>
<d:Calmonth>201309</d:Calmonth>
<d:BpCatX/>
<d:CusvalsgX/>
<d:SalesorgX/>
<d:FlagX/>
<d:CalmonthX/>
<d:Customer>1000000167</d:Customer>
<d:ProdHier/>
<d:CompCode>DE0J</d:CompCode>
<d:HierX/>
<d:OrdMeth/>
<d:Nptotcap>2200.000</d:Nptotcap>
<d:Type/>
<d:Code>000</d:Code>
<d:Message/>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>...</id>
<title type="text">...</title>
<updated>2014-05-22T08:44:46Z</updated>
<category term="GET_AVG_CONS.Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<link href="Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR_COLLECTION(Customer='1000000167',CompCode='DE0J')" rel="edit" title="Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR"/>
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:BpCat/>
<d:Cusvalsg/>
<d:Salesorg/>
<d:Flag/>
<d:Calmonth>201310</d:Calmonth>
<d:BpCatX/>
<d:CusvalsgX/>
<d:SalesorgX/>
<d:FlagX/>
<d:CalmonthX/>
<d:Customer>1000000167</d:Customer>
<d:ProdHier/>
<d:CompCode>DE0J</d:CompCode>
<d:HierX/>
<d:OrdMeth/>
<d:Nptotcap>220.000</d:Nptotcap>
<d:Type/>
<d:Code>000</d:Code>
<d:Message/>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

This is part of the response from linq query selecting all colums:

[image]

And this is the response when I select only some of the columns in linq query:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

@Zoe

The request which is sent by browser as well as from application, which results in duplicated entries, is the same:

IPaddress:port/something/GET_AVG_CONS/Y_AVG_CONS_COLLECTION()?$filter=Customer eq '1000000167'.

The request from application, which results in correct entries is:

IPaddress:port/something/GET_AVG_CONS/Y_AVG_CONS_YEAR_COLLECTION()?$filter=Customer eq '1000000167'&$select=Calmonth,Nptotcap.

@christiandev

I don't understand your question. I'm using linq query. Before the query is executed, there are no entries in collection. After the execution, they are already duplicated.

Comment: What is your actual request sent by the client? Can you capture the request in the fiddler, and post the difference between respective request sent by client and browser here?

Comment: If you use a break point at the query (before being passed back via WCF), is the Data duplicated there?